# Service Activator reuse not working

Tags: spring-integration

In the service activator documentation it says:

> Using a "ref" attribute is generally recommended if the custom Service Activator handler implementation can be reused in other  definitions.

But the below snippet gives me

> IllegalArgumentException: An AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler may only be referenced once

```
<bean id="groupResequencer" class="com.core.flow.GroupResequencer"/>
<int:service-activator id="groupResequencer1" ref="groupResequencer"/>
<int:service-activator id="groupResequencer2" ref="groupResequencer"/>
```

When I change my bean definition to prototype it works but the `onInit()` method gets called twice, once with a generic component name and the second time with the spring integration service activator id as component name.

It doesn't matter to me whether the bean is singleton or prototype but I need a clean creation that happens only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to improve that documentation - it only applies when the `ref` references a POJO.

Some time ago, we added an optimization to service activator such that if the ref bean is an `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` we reference it directly rather than wrapping it in a new handler, to avoid that overhead.

Since such a bean can only have one `outputChannel` we can't use it in more than one endpoint. Making it a prototype means each service activator gets its own instance.

If you change your bean to a POJO rather than extending from ARPMH you can reuse it that way.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!